# Where are IIS error pages stored?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, application-pool

I have a webhosting company. When a client does not I stop their sites app_pool
and in the web.config I add:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://account.SimpleTix.com/Suspended/" exactDestination="false" httpResponseStatus="Found">
        <clear />
    </httpRedirect>
```

However, since the app_pool is turned off the redirect does not happen and the 503 error appears.
If I turn the app_pool on, the nice redirect happens.
I'd rather not have extra app_pools running though.
Is there a way to set the error 503 html code? I could just add a basic http refresh meta tag.

example...
http://wongfurockauditorium.simpletix.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are some you cannot customize, which are mentioned in this article,

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103(v=ws.10).aspx

> You cannot customize the following HTTP errors: 400, 403.9, 411, 414,
>   500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503, and 505.